# Manage Internal Users permission missing

Tags: profile

In my dev org, I have PermissionsManageInternalUsers field on Profile but this is missing in org where I am trying to install package.

Comment: What edition is the org you're trying to install? If it's anything below Enterprise (Professional, Group, etc.), you will be missing some features. Not sure whether the exact permission you mention is among the missing ones, but it's worth checking

Comment: Its Enterprise edition only. Salesforce support team responded back with "External Sharing Model" needs to be enabled on org first. I could not understand for manage Internal User Setting, why "External Sharing Model" needs to be enabled